# Jmeter with InfluxDB Data mismatch issue

Tags: jmeter, devops, grafana, load-testing, influxdb

I have a Jmeter setup where I have added backend listener as influxDB our setup is like we have individual EC2 instances act as single standalone server ( **Distributed Master load test** ).

So logically the rate of ActiveThreads going to generate the load is as follows:-

**Desired-Behaviour** - Thread group 2000 * Instance 10 = 20000 ( **ACTIVE THREADS** ).
**Actual Behaviour** - Instead we are getting 2000 as **ACTIVE THREADS** only.

We have tried deploying InfluxDB v1 and Influx v2 both and result ends the same.[Grafana Dashboard with influxdb as datasource showing 2k active threads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIqu4.png).

[JMX thread group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmz6z.png).

[JMX file backend listener configs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4QqF.png).

Can anyone please let me know if any configuration changes is needed to be done to generate this much amount of Load with active threads.

Answer (score 0):

Given you properly configured:

1. JMeter in terms of [Remote Hosts and RMI Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
2. Grafana in terms of [properly setting up queries in panels](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-grafana)

You should see the real number of active threads in your dashboard

Here is a [demo](https://i.imgur.com/Ag5JL1t.mp4), as you can see when I increase JMeter Slave pod count to 2 the number of threads increases twice.